# JS fetch sending null data to backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make a simple POST request ( To a Spring backend) that will add entries to my database. However, my fetch function seems to be sending null values even though console logging the data in question appears to look right. This is, of course, creating null values in my database. What's strange is that the payload for the request is blank in the dev tools, but there definitely is data to be sent.

console logging the state object newInvestment after inputting something for example produces: `{"invname":"Microsoft","description":"Tech","ticker":"MSFT"}`

```
const [newInvestment, setNewInvestment] = useState({
    invname: "",
    description: "",
    ticker: ""
  })

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    setNewInvestment({...newInvestment, [e.target.name] : e.target.value})
  }

  

  const createInvestment = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()



    

    fetch("/api/investments", {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
      },
      method: "POST",
       body: JSON.stringify({
          "description": newInvestment["description"],
          "name": newInvestment["invname"],
          "ticker": newInvestment["ticker"],
        })
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) console.log(response);
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
      props.addInvestment() // closes the modal
  };
```

I tried console logging everything about my request to ensure there is data to be sent. I expected the body of the request to be filled with the values from my object that are specified. instead I am getting null values in my database with a 200 OK response. My backend should return the data that it receives, but it is returning undefined. This leads me to believe that the problem is in my front end.

Comment: is the POST data being sent? can you confirm that? it's unclear if the data is being sent in the first place

Comment: You can see the code you provided sends a request as intended: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-dgv7bm?file=App.tsx. Please try to recreate your error, you will probably find the problem while doing so.

Comment: Check the request body in network tab of Chrome dev tools. Your frontend code should work correctly